# Prevent soundmanager2 from playing a file

Tags: javascript, soundmanager2

How can I prevent soundmanager2 from playing a particular MP3 file inline. I want the user to have the option to either play the file inline, or download it. In order for them to be able to download the file I would need Soundmanager2 to ignore that particular anchor tag.

Any idea how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured, very simple in fact. You just need to add a class "inline-exclude" for the anchor tags you want Soundmanager to ignore. So something like:

The song that would be ignored.